# Either/OR class diagram

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

I'm working with exams in UML, and hope someone will be able to answer my question.

In the problem domain it says that every customer attending the event will have a contract, both inviduals and organizers. I ended up with a class diagram where I made associations between both inviduals and organizers to the contract class, please look at the attachment.

My question: Am I allowed to say that EITHER a invidual sign a contract OR an organizer sign a contract, by making associations to both?

[image]

Comment: You need to tell what the contract's purpose is. Are that 2 different contracts (likely)? If so, which nature is either?

Comment: The purpose is to record everyone attending the event (both inviduals and organizers). The difference is that orginaziers will have a more favorable rate to pay for his entrance. I'm not sure what you mean with "nature"?

Comment: Can you clarify - is only one of the sides signing contract? Your description is somewhat unclear to me.

Comment: Sure I can. I am glad you want to help. Yeah, only one of the sides are signing one spesific contract. They to not share contract . Hope that was a little bit more clear.

Comment: You say "record", but that's not a contract. A contract is about services. And organizer deliver service while individuals (attendees?) get a service.

Comment: Sorry, wrong choice of word. Everyone beeing at the event, both inviduals and organizers, are signing a contract. It is a software company delivering these services.. What I am wondering about is if it's okay to make assosiations to both, even though only one sign one spesific contract (not sharing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so the best is maybe to introduce the "Customer" concept as depicted below. The association between Customer and Contract means that one Customer signs one Contrat and a Contract is Signed by one Customer. The inheritance links between Customer and both Organizer and Individual means that they are Customer which is allowed to sign a Contract.

[image]

If you want to keep your orginal design, you can add a constraint to express the fact that either an Individual or an Organizer can sign a Contract but it seems les elegant for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your diagrams! I agree that the first one is the best one. I noticed that you are using arrows while making associations, is that the same as a straight line and an arrow next to the rolename (as in my diagram)?

Comment: It seems to be but I am not 100% sure. I would say that your notation is not UML compliant. The arrows mean navigability.   Note that if the Contract between Organizer and Invidual are different as suggested by Thomas killian, you should introduced both of them and associate them with the correct Customer...

Comment: No they are not the same. The filled black arrow in the OP's diagram is the read direction indicator for the label. (read this label in this direction)  You can consider it part of the label itself. The diagram from Red Beard shows the actual navigability, which is a property of the actual association(end).

Comment: Thank you @GeertBellekens, good to know. I'm not sure what you meant by "introducing both of them and associate them with the correct customer", Red Beard. Do you mean I should make two difference classes of contract, one invidualContract and one organizerContract?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question you should use a `xor` linked to both associations. It can either be a dashed line going from one association to another, labeled `{xor}` or you can create a note with text `{xor}` and link it to both associations. You have to change the multiplicity end to `0..1` to avoid ill formed diagram.

Xor means exactly one link respective to one of the two associations exists for a particular contract.

Xor is specifically described in the [UML specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/). In version 2.5.1 (current) of the specification it's in section 7.6.5, Figure 7.16.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking for! I didn't know is was allowed with xor notation, but it seems resonable

Comment: Please consider upvoting and eventually marking the answer as a solution that worked for you :-)

Comment: I have added the best possible reference - directly to the UML specification.